# Schrödinger picture operators that depend on time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology

I have been reading up on the Schrödinger picture of quantum mechanics. In this picture it is often said (e.g. [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RGoQBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA41&dq=schrodinger%20picture%20explicit%20time%20dependence&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji9uu3wJXPAhXECMAKHZgACjg4ChDoAQg_MAU#v=onepage&q=schrodinger%20picture%20explicit%20time%20dependence&f=false)) that the operators are time-independent unless they depend explicitly on time. I cannot see what this is telling us since it seems to be saying that operators are time-independent unless they are not.  Is this not exactly the same for the Heisenberg picture which is said to have time-dependent operators? i.e. what does the above saying actually mean and how does it distinguish the time-dependence of operators in the Schrödinger and Heisenberg pictures?

Comment: In Schrodinger picture, you can have a time-varying Hamiltonian $H(t)$ if, say, you flip an external field on and off.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of constant operator (please, see the disclaimer at the end of this post) differs in the two pictures. Specifically (here $U(t,t_0)$ is the time evolution operator):

---

**Schrödinger picture**: an operator $A_S (t)$ is constant if $$A_S(t)= A_S(t_0) \qquad $$
for all $t$.

**Heisenberg picture**: an operator $A_H (t)$ is constant if: $$U(t,t_0)A_H(t)U^{\dagger}(t,t_0)=A_H (t_0)$$
for all $t$.

---

Since the two pictures are connected by: $$A_H (t)=U^{\dagger}(t,t_0)A_S(t)U(t,t_0),$$
the constancy of an operator can be checked in either picture.

The point is that a non-constant operator is an operator whose *definition* is changing with time.

Consider for example a non-relativistic free particle. The **Schrodinger** operator: $$x (t) = x + \frac{p}{m}t$$
is an operator whose definition is changing with time. Note that I have *declared* that $x(t)$ is a Schrodinger operator or, more precisely, that the time dependence in $x(t)$ is that of the Schrodinger picture. If, on the other hand, I had told you that $x(t)$ was a **Heisenberg operator**, then it would have been a constant operator, namely the constant operator: $$x_H(t)=e^{iHt}xe^{-iHt}.$$

When one introduces an operator valued function $t\mapsto A(t)$, it must always be clear to what dynamical scheme he is referring to.

---

**Disclaimer.** I've just noticed that my above definition of “constant” operator (which, to be clear, is just my personal jargon) may cause some confusion with what is usually called a *conserved* operator. A conserved operator is by definition one whose matrix elements $$\langle \alpha (t)\vert A(t)\vert \beta (t)\rangle$$ are constant, where the kets and the operators are referred to *any scheme*. This translates, respectively, to the requirement: $$U(t,t_0)A_S (t)U(t,t_0)=A_S(t_0)$$ in the Schrodinger scheme and: $$A_H (t)=A_H (t_0)\,\,(\,=A_S(t_0)!)$$in the Heisenberg scheme.

For example, the Heisenberg operator: $$\mathbf K (t) = \dfrac{\intop\text d ^3 \mathbf x \mathcal H (\mathbf x ,t ) \mathbf x }{\intop\text d ^3 \mathbf x \mathcal H (\mathbf x ,t )}-\mathbf P t,$$ where $\mathcal H $ and $\mathbf P$ are the hamiltonian density and momentum of the free Klein-Gordon field, is a *conserved* operator but not a *constant* operator.

Comment: So..., the **Schrödinger** operator $x(t)$ is not an observable ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas why would you say that?

Comment: Because in Schrödinger's picture, observables are time-independent. In particular, the position and momentum operators, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/456724/are-hat-x-and-hat-p-assumed-to-be-time-independent-operators

Comment: @onurcanbektas here I was not addressing the question whether an operator is an observable or not. Usually, in QM, hermitian operators are assumed to represent observable quantities (apart from density matrices, which are hermitian but used to characterize the state of a system, instead). Anyway, in the **Schrodinger** picture the $x$ operator would be time-independent, $x(t)=x(t_0)$, and yes it represent an observable quantity.

Comment: Ok, everything is mixed now; if $x(t) = x(0) + \frac{ p(0)}{m } t $, then how can it is a Schrödinger operator ?  it is be time-dependent ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas OK, there is some confusion here, let me restate my point. If a **Schrodinger** operator $\xi_S(t)$ is defined as $\xi _S (t)\equiv x+pt/m$, it has a different physical intepretation from the *Heisenberg* position operator $x_H(t)$, even though they share the same mathematical expression as linear operators on the Hilbert space: $\xi_S(t)=x_H(t)$. On the other hand, if we define $x_S(t)=x$, then $x_S(t)$ and $x_H(t)$ have different mathematical expressions, but the same physical interpretation. In any case, I'm not implying that $\xi _S$  is not a physical observable.

Comment: By the way, why $x_H(t)=e^{iHt}xe^{-iHt}.$ is a constant operator (in Heisenberg's sense) ?

Answer (score 2):

> the operators are time-independent unless they depend explicitly on time. I cannot see what this is telling us...

The confusion is due to unfortunate terminology. There is a difference between "explicitly does not depend on time" and "time-independent".

**Operator does not explicitly depend on time**:

It is assumed that every operator is, in general, a function of coordinate and momenta operators $x_i$ and $p_i$ and time parameter $t$. If the operator is special in the sense it can be expressed, at all times, as value of the *same function of coordinates and momenta*, it is said that **it does not explicitly depend on time**. For example, the operator given by the function $U(x,p,t)=kx^2/2$ does not explicitly depend on time but the operator given by the function $U_1(x,p,t)= kx^2/2-qEx\cos\Omega t$ does.

**Operator is time-independent**:

Operator $\hat{A}_t$ is time-independent when it maps any vector $\psi_0$ to the same image counterpart vector $\psi_0'$ at all times:

$$
\forall t: \hat{A}_t \psi_0 = \psi_0'
$$

An operator that does not explicitly depend on time, such as $k\hat{x}^2/2$, can be time-independent, but not necessarily.

If $\hat{x},\hat{p}$ are time-independent, as in the Schroedinger picture, $k\hat{x}^2/2$ is time-independent as well.

However, if $\hat{x}$ or $\hat{p}$ is time-dependent, as in the Heisenberg picture, $k\hat{x}^2/2$ may be time-dependent, even if it does not depend explicitly on time.

Comment: I thought $\hat x, \hat p$ are assumed to be time-independent operators,  see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/456724/are-hat-x-and-hat-p-assumed-to-be-time-independent-operators

Comment: Those symbols do not have universal meaning. It depends on the "picture" - choice of formalism. In "Schroedinger picture" they are time-independent. In "Heisenberg picture", they evolve in time.

Comment: I implicitly assumed that when you write $U(x,p,t)=kx^2/2$, $x$ was corresponding to the "normal" form i.e from Schrödinger's point of view, of the operator.

Comment: In that sentence $x$ can be both, the normal or the Heisenberg operator. In both those cases, the operator $U$ does not depend explicitly on time, both only in Schroedinger's picture it is constant in time.

Comment: It may help to note that dependence of those symbols on time, explicit or not, is a general mathematical property, it is good to understand the difference without mixing in quantum theory specifics such as the choice of Schroedinger or Heisenberg picture.

Comment: So, in a sense, are you saying saying that the operator might change in time mathematically, but Schrödinger's picture includes that change into the ket the system is in. Similarly, in Heisenbergs picture, the change in the key is included into the operator.

Comment: For example, if we denote $\hat x$ is the operator that correspond to the position observable in our main formalism,  $\hat x_S$ is the operator where the time dependence of $\hat x$ is stripped away, and included into ket. Similarly, $\hat x_H$ is the operator in which the time dependence of  the ket together all of the operator $\hat x$ is contained, in a sense ?

Comment: Schroedinger's picture does not make all operators independent of time, only operators $x$ and $p$ and their functions. There are time-dependent operators in Schr. picture, like $U_1$ above.

Comment: What Heisenberg picture does is to strip $\psi$ of time dependence and put it into operators. The operator may or may not have been time-dependent before the change of picture.

Comment: I see; however, the answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/456724/are-hat-x-and-hat-p-assumed-to-be-time-independent-operators/456731#456731 explicitly states that $\hat x$ is not time-dependent (in the Schrödinger's sense), so I'm really confused in  here.

Comment: DanielC's answer does not mention $\hat{x}$ explicitly, he is talking generally. Also, $\hat{x}$ *is not* time-dependent in Schr. picture.

Comment: So, when you wrote $\hat H = k\hat{x}^2/2$ and were talking about time-dependence of $\hat x$, you actually meant $\hat H = k\hat{x_H}^2/2$ ?

Comment: Where did I write that?

Comment: My mistake, say $\hat B = k \hat x^2  /2$.

Answer (score -1):

Time dependence comes in many ways. Not just explicit time dependence. What Schrödinger picture says is that the state of a system evolves with time but the operators which are used to measure the position for example, they are fixed. So if you measure the position at two different times they have different probability density because the state has evolved.

On the other hand Heisenberg picture says that a unique system is determined by a unique state vector. But if you now want to measure the position in two different times you'll need two different operators.